# Audacity crashes when clicking the recording button

Tags: arch-linux, crash, audio-recording, audacity, dump

I've installed Audacity 3.4.2 on an up-to-date ArchLinux, using via `sudo pacman -S audacity`.

If I open it and click the record button (or alternatively hit <kbd>r</kbd>), it crashes. And by crash I mean that if I launch it from the terminal, as soon as I press the record button, its window closes and the message ***(Aborted) core dumped*** is printed in the terminal.

Given the malfunction is a crash with no useful message, I have no clue where to start from as far as troubleshooting goes.

So the question is: how do I troubleshoot, so that I can understand why the program crashes and maybe find a fix?

Comment: what is your question? ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: I know nothing of Arch Linux, but they have a page [General troubleshooting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/General_troubleshooting) which might help you narrow down the problem enough to give us more details to help you.

Comment: @jsotola, what question could the text you read above possibly imply? "How do I fix it?", maybe? But just _maybe_...

Comment: @Enlico `how to debug?` ... `where are the configuration files?` ... `where are the log files?` ... `how to start program in safe mode?` etc. etc. ... not everyone will ask the same question ... what is yours? ... please edit the post

Comment: Enlico, note that different people have different questions, and if we'd assumed one question you may have gotten frustrated at that assumption. Please clearly and specifically spell out your question in the post. Use the EDIT button to add information to your post, including a specific question, listing the research that you have done, and the things that you have tried.

Comment: How was it installed? Snap, https://snapcraft.io/install/audacity/arch ? App image from GitHub, https://www.audacityteam.org/download/linux/? Pcklages, https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Audacity?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, no, I've installed audacity via the way packages are meant to be installed on Archlinux, otherwise I'd have specified: with `pacman`.

Comment: @jsotola, a program that crashes is just broken, one way or another. I have no clue why I should ask about config files. Start a program in safe mode? What is that?

Comment: @Enlico I never said that you should ask about config files ... I said that you should not assume that everybody would ask the same question ... safe mode is an option to start a program without any additional plugins that may have been installed ... it prevents a failing plugin from causing problems